# Find the Intersection Between a Sphere and a Plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, spheres, plane-geometry

The question is as follows:

> Show that the sphere $(x−5)^2 +(y+2)^2 +(z−4)^2 = 36$ and the plane $2x+y+2z = 34$ have exactly one point in common.

The problem gave the hint that solving the two equations simultaneously will not be a good approach to this problem. If they do not want for me to subsitute one equation into the other, then how will I be able to solve this problem? Do they want parametric equations? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having only one point in common occurs if and only if the plane is tangent to the sphere, so we can try to show the plane is a tangent plane. This will occur if the minimum distance from the plane to the centre of the sphere is the radius of the sphere, i.e. $6$. The minimum distance occurs at a point where the normal line passes through the centre of the sphere, essentially by Pythagoras. The unit normal to the plane is $(2,1,2)/3$, and the point on the sphere in this direction from the centre is
$$ (5,-2,4)+6\left( \frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3} \right) = (5,-2,4)+(4,2,4) = (9,0,8). $$
Then $(9,0,8) \cdot (2,1,2) = 18+16=34$, so $(9,0,8)$ indeed lies in the plane as well. Hence it is the only point in common.